# how remove a point on the line chart (geom_line) R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I need your help. I need to remove the point number 8, x = "180" from multiple lines geom_line, but remaining at geom_point. What should you do?

Data is in an excel spreadsheet

```
data<-melt(CB_fechado, id.vars = 'a');
#Ângulo de incidência de vento
#print(data)

Grafico_CB_fechado <- ggplot(data,aes(x =`Ângulo de incidência de vento [°]`, y=`value`, color=`variable`))+
geom_line() + geom_point()+ 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,180), breaks = c(0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180))+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))+ 
ylab("b")+theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

For exemplo

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about subsetting the data that you use for the `geom_line()`. Not that this would be a bit more complex if it were not the last point. Here is an example with similar dummy data since I did not want to type in from the image.

**dummy data**

```
data <- data.frame(angle = rep(c(0:6*15, 180), 4),
                   cat = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 8),
                   value = rep(1:4/-4, each = 8))
```

**subset data**

Drop points with angle = 180.

```
data_lines <- data[data$angle != 180,]
```

**graph it**

Use `data_lines` instead of `data` in `geom_line()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = angle, y = value, color= cat)) +
  geom_line(data = data_lines) +
  geom_point()+ 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,180), breaks = c(0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))+ 
  ylab("b")+theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: example ggplot2]

Comment: for new case multiple lines ?

Comment: I think it should just work. You could also do `data[-8,]` or something to be more specific about the point.

Comment: understanding, but the data variable eliminates only one line 180º not making the other . Should eliminate -8, -16, -24 .. how would you do that?

Comment: Okay, I think I follow. I edited to do what I think you want, but with representative dummy data.

Comment: @ Adam Thank you very much!! It got me a lot of a headache. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a subset of the data in the `ggplot` call. In this case I use `subset` to remove the point with `a = 180`.
Note that I redefine the color argument to `"red"`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = a, y = b, color = "red")) +
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line(data = subset(data, a != 180)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,180), breaks = c(0,15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.5,1.5))+ 
  ylab("b") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
data <- read.table(text = "
    a       b
1   0   0.57395085
2   15  0.47593420
3   30  0.30175686
4   45  0.13363012
5   60  -0.02727459
6   75  -0.17971621
7   90  -0.44955122
8   180 -0.30247414
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: for new case multiple lines?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira If you are grouping by `color=variable` it should be automatic. Change that in my code, no `color = "red"`.